# clock_gettime fails in chrooted Debian etch with CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID

Tags: c++, ubuntu, debian, clock, chroot

I have setup a chrooted Debian Etch (32bit) under Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit), and it appears that clock_gettime() works with CLOCK_MONOTONIC, but fails with both CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID and CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID. The errno is set to EINVAL, which according to the man page means that "The clk_id specified is not supported on this system."

All three clocks work fine outside the chrooted Debian and in 64bit chrooted Debian etch.

Can someone explains to me why this is the case and how to fix it?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I can't find any reasonable explanation. Can you run a test under strace and show what it prints for the clock_gettime calls? Also your kernel version would be nice to know.

Comment: I ran strace on the simplest example I can think of and this is the output https://gist.github.com/3436182. The code is at https://gist.github.com/3436249. I am new to stackoverflow, do let me know if I should edit the original question to include these information.

Comment: The kernel version I got from running 'uname -r' under both the host system and the chroot system is 3.2.0-29-generic.

Comment: clock_gettime doesn't appear in the strace at all. That means the EINVAL is coming from glibc or the vdso. This is a serious debugging challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the cause yet, but I have ideas that won't fit in the comment box.

First, you can make the test program simpler by compiling it as C instead of C++ and not linking it to libpthread. `-lrt` should be good enough to get `clock_gettime`. Also, compiling it with `-static` could make tracing easier since the dynamic linker startup stuff won't be there.

Static linking might even change the behavior of clock_gettime. It's worth trying just to find out whether it works around the bug.

Another thing I'd like to see is the output of this vdso-bypassing test program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    if(syscall(SYS_clock_gettime, CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &ts)) {
        perror("clock_gettime");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID: %lu.%09ld\n",
           (unsigned long)ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
    return 0;
}
```

with and without `-static`, and if it fails, add `strace`.

### Update (actually, skip this. go to the second update)

A couple more simple test ideas:

1. compile and run a 32-bit test program in the Ubuntu host system, by adding `-m32` to the gcc command. It's possible that the kernel's 32-bit compatibility mode is causing the error. If that's the case, then the 32-bit version will fail no matter which libc it gets linked to.
2. take the non-static test programs you compiled under Debian, copy them to the Ubuntu host system and try to run them there. Change in behavior will point to libc as the cause.

Then it's time for the hard stuff. Looking at disassembled code and maybe single-stepping it in gdb. Instead of having you do that on your own, I'd like to get a copy of the code you're running. Upload a a static-compiled failing test program somewhere I can get it. Also a copy of the 32-bit vdso provided by your kernel might be interesting. To extract the vdso, run the following program (compiled in the 32-bit chroot) which will create a file called `vdso.dump`, and upload that too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int getvseg(const char *which, const char *outfn)
{
  FILE *maps, *outfile;
  char buf[1024];
  void *start, *end;
  size_t sz;
  void *copy;
  int ret;
  char search[strlen(which)+4];

  maps = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
  if(!maps) {
    perror("/proc/self/maps");
    return 1;
  }
  outfile = fopen(outfn, "w");
  if(!outfile) {
    perror(outfn);
    fclose(maps);
    return 1;
  }

  sprintf(search, "[%s]\n", which);
  while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, maps)) {
    if(strlen(buf)<strlen(search) ||
       strcmp(buf+strlen(buf)-strlen(search),search))
      continue;
    if(sscanf(buf, "%p-%p", &start, &end)!=2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "weird line in /proc/self/maps: %s", buf);
      continue;
    }
    sz = (char *)end - (char *)start;
    /* copy because I got an EFAULT trying to write directly from vsyscall */
    copy = malloc(sz);
    if(!copy) {
      perror("malloc");
      goto fail;
    }
    memcpy(copy, start, sz);
    if(fwrite(copy, 1, sz, outfile)!=sz) {
      if(ferror(outfile))
        perror(outfn);
      else
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: short write", outfn);
      free(copy);
      goto fail;
    }
    free(copy);
    goto success;
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "%s not found\n", which);

fail:
  ret = 1;
  goto out;
success:
  ret = 0;
out:
  fclose(maps);
  fclose(outfile);
  return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
  int ret = 1;
  if(!getvseg("vdso", "vdso.dump")) {
    printf("vdso dumped to vdso.dump\n");
    ret = 0;
  }
  if(!getvseg("vsyscall", "vsyscall.dump")) {
    printf("vsyscall dumped to vsyscall.dump\n");
    ret = 0;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

### Update 2

I reproduced this by downloading an etch libc. It's definitely caused be glibc stupidity. Instead of a simple syscall wrapper for clock_gettime it has a big wad of preprocessor spaghetti culminating in "you can't use clockid's that we didn't pre-approve". You're not going to get it to work with that old glibc. Which brings us to the question I didn't want to ask: why are you trying to use an obsolete version of Debian anyway?

Comment: Compiling the original test program as C in chroot and using -static gives the following very short trace, https://gist.github.com/3451000, which as you pointed out, does not contain clock_gettime at all, unlike the strace output of the same program under the host Ubuntu system, https://gist.github.com/3451017.

Comment: The test program you provide appears to work. Without -static, I get something in the range of: CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID: 0.000882401. With -static, the output is in the range of CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID: 0.000348041, the correspond strace output also contains call to clock_gettime, https://gist.github.com/3451107

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to build some shared libraries so that they can be run on servers with older libraries (GLIBC 2.3.6 and possibly others). After much googling, it seems that a chrooted build environment is the best option and Debian etch has GLIBC 2.3.6. I don't have much experience with these things, so I may have missed some obvious and simpler options.

Comment: I'd also like the same shared library to work on both older and newer systems, and moving the dynamically linked test program out of chroot does work, so at least that is a plus. Btw, much appreciated for your help.

Comment: If you include your own clock_gettime function in your library, implemented using `syscall()` like I showed you, that should at least handle any calls from within the library.